# Residuals from ARMA estimation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression, autoregressive-models

I am trying to use the function armaxfilter from the MFE toolbox, but I get an error:

`>> parameters = armaxfilter(y,1,1,1);
??? Error: File: armaxfilter.m Line: 477 Column: 21
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.`

Apparently my code is correct, as can be seen from an example from help:
  EXAMPLE:
    To fit a standard ARMA(1,1), use

```
parameters = armaxfilter(y,1,1,1)
```

Any idea on what is wrong?
In any case, my aim is getting residuals from an ARMA model estimation on a time series, a suggestion on an alternative way would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code (from [here](http://www.kevinsheppard.com/MFE_Toolbox#Code)) , the issue is probably with the tilde output. If you are using an old version of MATLAB which does not support ~, you may get the error you mention.

There is a simple way to check this. Try out at the command line:

```
[~,idx] = min(1:10)
```

If this causes an error, you are using a version of MATLAB which does not support ~. If you want to use that particular code, you will have to either upgrade your MATLAB, or edit all the files such that examples of the tilde are replaced with some sort of dummy variable, e.g.:

```
[garbage,idx] = min(1:10)
```

Comment: I am indeed using al old version of matlab, that was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

As the error message describes, the problem lies in the armaxfilter.m. You should open that file and see what code is written at the specified line. I am sure you will see a bug in there.